# Is there a way to nullify cookie in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I tried

```
if (Request.Cookies["IsGuest"] != null)
     {
       Response.Cookies["IsGuest"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
       //HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("IsGuest");
       //myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
       //Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
     }
    string a = Request.Cookies["IsGuest"].Value;
```

But `Request.Cookies["IsGuest"]` is never null.
Commenting uncommented code and doing vice versa also did not help.

Comment: Does null-checking for `Request.Cookies["IsGuest"].Value` work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Request.Cookies["IsGuest"] != null || Request.Cookies["IsGuest"].Value != "")
     {
       Response.Cookies["IsGuest"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
       //HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("IsGuest");
       //myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
       //Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
     }
string a = Request.Cookies["IsGuest"].Value;
```

I think your Cookie exists but it has no value.
If it's not work, look whats in string a and than you can compare it in the first row.